# My onClickListener is not getting called when I change pages in my fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, imageview, onclicklistener, buttonclick

In my Fragment, I have three controls: two `ImageViews` and a `Button`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rel_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/heading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/forward"
        android:background="@drawable/chevronright"
        android:layout_below="@+id/heading"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:background="@drawable/chevronleft"
        android:layout_below="@+id/heading"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/skip_button"
        android:text="@string/skip_button"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/back"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/heading" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the fragment, I define `onClickListeners` for all three controls:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("WDWHIC settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("lastPage", INTRO);
    editor.commit();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_intro, container, false);

    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.intro_page_full);

    RelativeLayout topLayout = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.topLayout);
    topLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    final Animation in = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    in.setDuration(500);

    RelativeLayout rel_layout = view.findViewById(R.id.rel_layout);

    Resources res = getResources();

    pages = res.getStringArray(R.array.pages_array);

    heading = rel_layout.findViewById(R.id.heading);
    heading.setText(pages[pageNum]);

    forward = rel_layout.findViewById(R.id.forward);
    forward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            back.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pageNum += 2;
            heading.setText(pages[pageNum]);
            body.startAnimation(in);
            body.setText(pages[pageNum + 1]);
            body.scrollTo(0, 0);
            if (pageNum == 2 * MAX_PAGES) forward.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });

    back = rel_layout.findViewById(R.id.back);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            forward.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pageNum -= 2;
            heading.setText(pages[pageNum]);
            body.startAnimation(in);
            body.setText(pages[pageNum + 1]);
            body.scrollTo(0, 0);
            if (pageNum == 0) back.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });

    skip = rel_layout.findViewById(R.id.skip_button);
    skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditProfileFragment editProfileFragment = new EditProfileFragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, editProfileFragment, editProfileFragment.getTag()).commit();
            getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
        }
    });

    body = rel_layout.findViewById(R.id.body);
    body.startAnimation(in);
    body.setText(pages[pageNum + 1]);
    body.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    return view;
}
```

If I click on the '`skip`' button while on the first page, its `onClick`() method gets called. But if I click on forward or back, it doesn't unless I return to the first page. What's up with this? Why should advancing pages make a difference?

Comment: Try adding `android:clickable="true"` to your image views

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:clickable="true"` to your image views.

In the documentation:

> android:clickable     Defines whether this view reacts to click events.
>   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:clickable

Therefore, in theory, the View's onClickListener won't be fire if clickable is not set to true.

Comment: I don't understand how that would help, since the onClick listeners for both ImageViews works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting the onClickListener functionality in the class that extends FragmentActivity.

In the class that implements your onCreateView method define a static handler and initialized it with the static handler that should be defined in the class that extends FragmentActivity.

from the class that implements onCreateView create an android message to send to the static handler of your class that extends FragmentActivity. In this message send an object which is your button that will implement the onClickListener. Note: Create and send this message from inside your onCreateView.

Once the message is received inside the class that extends FragmentActivity, send the 
object that arrives in the message( which is a view that is actually your button) as a parameter to a private method that resides inside your class that extends FragmentActivity.

Inside this private method try to set the onClickListener functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't see how it explains why the Button onClick listener works on the first page but not the others.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this should work, but I moved the button above the heading, without changing anything else, and now onClick() gets called from every page.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/skip_button"
    android:text="@string/skip_button"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/heading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/skip_button"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
```

[image]